# Drilldown details for DAX measure

Tags: dax

I am newer to DAX and I have created a formula based on forecast and actuals. I have these 2, 1 for total forecast and 1 for year to go forecast.

```
Forecast:
SUMX(
  FILTER(
    Forecast_Revenue,
    Forecast_Revenue[AMOUNT<> 0
  ),
  Forecast_Revenue[Amount]
)

YTG:
SUMX(
  FILTER(
    Forecast_Revenue,
    Forecast_Revenue[End of Month]>TODAY() &&
    Forecast_Revenue[End of Month] IN VALUES(Forecast_Revenue[End of Month])
  ),
  Forecast_Revenue[Amount]
)
```

I want to create the measure which correctly demonstrates in the pivot table the value of the YTG forecast and when drilling into a cell in the pivot table, correctly shows the measure including filtering of data which should not be included (IE past dates).

I created the formulas and I tried using CALCULATE or SUMX and trying different methods of filtering.

I wanted the drill down to show the filtered data.

This is the Pivot Table:
[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXWpQ.png)

And this is the drill down for it:
[Drilldown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMVm8.png)

How do I get the drill down in the Pivot Table with a measure designed to show what the remaining forecast is only show relevant data?